# Java Exception Handling Assignment

Tags: java, exception

So I've recently learned exception handling for Java and I'm still trying to get used to it and all but I feel like I'm missing something. I was doing an assignment for my class and the compiler doesn't like my code.

I'm supposed to be making a Calculator that takes in an operator and then a number, and if the operator (+, -, *, /) given is not one of the aforementioned four, then an exception is thrown.

I used try-catch but for some reason the try and catch aren't recognizing each other unless I place them next to each other which isn't really what I want.

My question is really: Is there a way for my try and catch to recognize each other without being right next to each other, so I can run code in-between them? Or is that impossible and I'm doing it all wrong?

Here's my code so far:

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class Calculator 
 {
        public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String operatorInput;
    double numberInput;
    String userRedo = "Y";
    double result = 0.0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in an arithmetic operator of your choice and press enter.");
    System.out.println("Then, please type in a number that will undergo the operation.");

    while((userRedo.toUpperCase()).compareTo("Y")==0) 
    {
        try 
        {
            operatorInput = input.nextLine();
            if(operatorInput.compareTo("+")!=0||operatorInput.compareTo("-")!=0||
               operatorInput.compareTo("*")!=0||operatorInput.compareTo("/")!=0) 
            {
                throw new UnknownOperatorException("Unknown operator!");
            }   
        }

        numberInput = input.nextDouble();
        if(operatorInput.compareTo("+")==0) 
        {
            result += numberInput;
        } else if(operatorInput.compareTo("-")==0) 
        {
            result -= numberInput;
        } else if(operatorInput.compareTo("*")==0) 
        {
            result = result * numberInput;
        } else
        {
            result = result / numberInput;
        }

        System.out.println("\nresult "+operatorInput+" "+numberInput+"= ");
        System.out.println("Updated result: "+result);
        System.out.println("Again? (y/n)");
        userRedo = input.nextLine();


        catch(UnknownOperatorException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }   
    }
}
```

}

And here's the exception class I made:

```
    public class UnknownOperatorException extends Exception 
    {
public UnknownOperatorException() 
{
    super("Please select an actual operator and try again: ");
}

public UnknownOperatorException(String message)
{
    super(message);
}
```

}

Comment: Try and catch have to be next to each other. If there's something you're trying to accomplish by having them separate there's probably a way to make that work

Comment: Oh really? I guess I'll have to change the way I'm doing things then. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: It seems strange that you would be throwing an exception **and catching the *same* exception** in one method. If it were me, I'd throw the exception in one method, and catch it in the method where I call the first method. Are you sure that your assignment doesn't ask you to do this?

Answer (score 2):

They have to be next to each other. There's a few things you could do:

Move the `}` at the commented line down a ways, like this

```
    while((userRedo.toUpperCase()).compareTo("Y")==0) 
    {
        try 
        {
            operatorInput = input.nextLine();
            if(operatorInput.compareTo("+")!=0||operatorInput.compareTo("-")!=0||
               operatorInput.compareTo("*")!=0||operatorInput.compareTo("/")!=0) 
            {
                throw new UnknownOperatorException("Unknown operator!");
            }   

        }//this one here
```

Take that and move it to here

```
    System.out.println("\nresult "+operatorInput+" "+numberInput+"= ");
    System.out.println("Updated result: "+result);

}// put it here
```

Then take these two lines

```
System.out.println("Again? (y/n)");
userRedo = input.nextLine();
```

And move them below the catch:

```
        catch(UnknownOperatorException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }   
        System.out.println("Again? (y/n)");
        userRedo = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

That will let your while loop still sort of function and make your try/catch work. You might need to tweak things a bit to make them work right though

Answer (score 0):

In order for try/catch to work, as Ghost says in a comment, you will need to put them next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

And the code above has some problems...

maybe this works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String operatorInput=null;
    double numberInput;
    String userRedo = "Y";
    double result = 0.0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in an arithmetic operator of your choice and press enter.");
    System.out.println("Then, please type in a number that will undergo the operation.");

    while ((userRedo.toUpperCase()).compareTo("Y") == 0) {
        try {
            operatorInput = input.nextLine().trim();
            if (operatorInput.compareTo("+") != 0
                    && operatorInput.compareTo("-") != 0
                    && operatorInput.compareTo("*") != 0
                    && operatorInput.compareTo("/") != 0) {
                throw new UnknownOperatorException("Unknown operator!");
            }

        } catch (UnknownOperatorException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            continue;
        }

        numberInput = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());

        if (operatorInput.compareTo("+") == 0) {
            result += numberInput;
        } else if (operatorInput.compareTo("-") == 0) {
            result -= numberInput;
        } else if (operatorInput.compareTo("*") == 0) {
            result = result * numberInput;
        } else {
            result = result / numberInput;
        }

        System.out.println("\nresult " + operatorInput + " " + numberInput + "= ");
        System.out.println("Updated result: " + result);
        System.out.print("Again? (y/n) : ");

        userRedo = input.nextLine();
    }

    input.close();
}
```

Comment: I just tried this out and while it does work, when the exception is thrown, there is no catch. As in, the System.out.println(e.getMessage()); does not display what it's supposed. It seems to be skipped entirely. Otherwise the code works properly.
EDIT: Never mind, the exception is being caught. The getMessage() method isn't displaying anything even though it should be being displayed to the screen.

Comment: yes, the UnknownOperatorException caughted at catch block, and we know  what happend, and why the exception caughted. so I coded just print the message and continue the while loop. I just think that above code will be help to you, because there are some bugs in your code.. ^^; cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Building implements CarbonFootprint {
    
    //implement 4a
    void getCarbonFootprint(){
    System.out.println("Kim Byers, CSIS 505, Exception Handling, Assignment1");
    
    //Building display
    double Bill;
    }
    
    //class variables
    double monthlyElectricBill;
    double monthlyGasBill;
        
    //constructor
    public void Building(double monthlyElectricBill, double monthlyGasBill) {
        monthlyElectricBill = ([monthyly Electric Billmonth;
        monthlyGasBill = monthlyGasBill;
            
    //Constructor
        
    //set method statements
}
```

Comment: Trying to complement your code with some explanation is a good practice.